# On AMP pages should amp-carousel elements have a lightbox attribute or not?

Tags: html, amp-html

I'm getting different conflicting AMP validation messages..

When I add a **lightbox** attribute to an **amp-carousel** element I get the following validation message.

```
The attribute 'lightbox' may not appear in tag 'amp-carousel'
```

But if I remove it, I get the following validation message..

```
The mandatory attribute 'lightbox' is missing in tag 'AMP-CAROUSEL. [lightbox]'
```

It feels like the AMP validator can't make up its mind.

I'm using this url.
https://leasing.com/car-leasing-news/2018-mercedes-s-class-coupe-cabriolet/amp/

on the following validator..

https://search.google.com/test/amp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `amp-lightbox-gallery-0.1.js` to add in header

```
<script async custom-element="amp-lightbox-gallery" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-lightbox-gallery-0.1.js"></script>
```

**After adding js screen shot**

[image]

**Before**

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I shall try this and award you with a much deserved Correct Answer should you prove to be correct.